# KeyError: 'user_id'

Tags: python, django

I wanna put dictionary data to the model(User) .I wrote like

```
 for row_number, row_data in dict_data.items():
            user1 = User.objects.filter(corporation_id=row_data['corporation_id'])
            if user1:       
               user1.update(user_id=dict_data['user_id'])
```

`dict_data` is dictionary type like

```
{'00010': OrderedDict([('corporation_id', '00001aB3D4'), ('user_id', '11111'), ('name', 'Tom'), ('age', '20')])}
```

I wanna put `dict_data` data's `user_id` to `user_id` column of `User`model. Definitely, `dict_data` has `'user_id'`, but I really cannot understand why this error happens.How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't you mean `row_data['user_id']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
dict_data["user_id"]
```

You need to use the unpacked element:

```
row_data["user_id"]
```

Or, in case you really want to use `dict_data` you have to first access the corresponding dictionary value:

```
dict_data[row_number]["user_id"]
```